# autoconf: Take -march into account for AX_CHECK_X86_FEATURES

Tags: gcc, autoconf

The AX_CHECK_X86_FEATURES autoconf macro checks for the CPU support for advances SIMD instruction, such as AVX512.

However even if passing `CFLAGS=-march=corei7`, the macro enables AVX512F. How can I build a compatible binary when passing such march argument, but take advantage of AVX512F when compiling with `-march=native`?

To broaden the ability to help, autoconf will actually generate the following C code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int
main ()
{
     __builtin_cpu_init ();
     if (__builtin_cpu_supports("avx512f"))
       return 0;
     return 1;
}
```

`gcc -march=corei7 -mtune=corei7 test.c -o test`

./test returns 0, while it shouldn't.